# how to convert HH:MM representation to minutes in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

how to convert varchar(hh:mm) to minutes in oracle sql.

For example:

```
HH:MM    Minutes
08:00    480
08:45    525
07:57    477
```

Comment: The question is rather why you're storing time values in a varchar column?

Comment: Your comments to the various responses make it clear that you are selecting from a table, and that seems to be giving you problems implementing the proposed solutions. So please **edit your question** to make it clearer. Include some sample data from your table and indicative output.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you require to Print 08:00 hours as 480 minutes,

Extract the Digit before `:` and multply with 60 and add the digit after `:`. So you can convert the **HH:MM** representation in to minutes.

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(ATT.workdur,'[^:]+',1,1)*60 + REGEXP_SUBSTR(ATT.workdur,'[^:]+',1,2) MINUTES FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: REPLACE('ATT.workdur',':')*0.60 MINUTES                                      
 Im getting Error ORA-01722: invalid number
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
*Action:   Specify a valid number.

Comment: Seems neat. Except `SELECT REPLACE('08:30',':')*0.60 MINUTES FROM DUAL;`. Oh dear.

Comment: @satz `REPLACE('ATT.workdur',':')` remove the quotes for `ATT.workdur`, ie; give `REPLACE(ATT.workdur,':')*0.60 MINUTES`

Comment: @TomJMuthirenthi Im Getting Like this 08:44 506.4
07:57 454.2
08:12 487.2
06:27 376.2
08:52 511.2
08:51 510.6

Comment: @satz Isnt that you are expecting? Can u share the expected resultes in the above mentioned case?

Comment: workdur 08:44,   524
07:57,477
08:12,
06:27,
08:52,
08:51

Comment: @satz I have corrected the answer as per your requirement and further usecases

Answer (score 1):

This will work even if the duration is 24 hours or greater:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fad2c9/2)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE durations ( duration ) AS
SELECT '00:30' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '07:57' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '08:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '12:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '20:01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '23:59' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '24:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '24:59' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT duration,
       ( (
         DATE '1970-01-01'
         + NUMTODSINTERVAL( SUBSTR( duration, 1, INSTR( duration, ':' ) - 1 ), 'HOUR' )
         + NUMTODSINTERVAL( SUBSTR( duration, INSTR( duration, ':' ) + 1 ), 'MINUTE' )
         )
         - DATE '1970-01-01'
       ) * 24 * 60 AS Minutes
FROM   durations
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fad2c9/2/0)**:

```
| DURATION | MINUTES |
|----------|---------|
|    00:30 |      30 |
|    07:57 |     477 |
|    08:00 |     480 |
|    12:00 |     720 |
|    20:01 |    1201 |
|    23:59 |    1439 |
|    24:00 |    1440 |
|    24:59 |    1499 |
```

However, there is an `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND` data type that would be better suited to your data:

```
CREATE TABLE your_table (
  duration INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND
);
```

Then you can just do:

```
INSERT INTO your_table ( duration ) VALUES ( INTERVAL '08:00' HOUR TO MINUTE );
```

To get the number of minutes you can then simply do:

```
SELECT ( ( DATE '1970-01-01' + duration ) - DATE '1970-01-01' ) *24*60 AS minutes
FROM   your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR('(08:00)',2,INSTR('(08:00)',':')-2))*60+TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR('(08:00)',INSTR('(08:00)',':')+1,2))
```

Comment: Im getting Null value   TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR('(ATT.workdur)',2,INSTR('(ATT.workdur)',':')-2))*60+TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR('(ATT.workdur)',INSTR('(ATT.workdur)',':')+1,2))

Comment: workdur 08:44, 524 07:57,477 08:12, 06:27, 08:52, 08:54

Comment: so what is hour and minute ? 08.ç44 or 08:12 or 08:52 or 08:54

Comment: for example 08:12 ,08 is hour and 12 is min

Comment: :) I want to ask which part you want to convert? there are many hours and minutes?

Answer (score 0):

If you can convert your input to a real date first, the task becomes much easier. Here, I have shamelessly appended the time to a fake date to create a date such as `2017-01-01 00:30`. To find out the number of minutes since midnight, you simply subtract the date for "midnight". It will return the difference in days, so you need to multiply by number of minutes per day to get what you want.

```
select time
      ,(to_date('2017-01-01 ' || time, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') - date '2017-01-01') * 24 * 60 as minutes
  from (select '00:30' as time from dual union all
        select '08:00' as time from dual union all       
        select '08:30' as time from dual union all
        select '12:00' as time from dual union all
        select '23:59' as time from dual
       );
```

Here is some sample input and output

```
time  minutes
====  =======
00:30      30
08:00     480
08:30     510
12:00     720
23:59   1 439
```

Comment: workdur  min
-------         ----
08:44 506.4
07:57 454.2
08:12 487.2

Comment: I get (07:57 -> 477), (08:12 -> 492), (08:44 -> 524). This is the number of minutes. Don't you want the number of minutes that the duration represents?

Comment: I don't understand. 07:57 = 7 hours (7*60 = 420 mins) + 57 minutes = 477. If you want 454.2, you need to show me the math :)

Comment: This will work provided the duration is between `00:00` and `23:59` - for larger values it will raise an `ORA-01850: hour must be between 0 and 23` exception.